# Does iCloud work with App data?

Tags: icloud

It seems like iCloud is designed to store an App's data, but it's not working for me. I am getting Photos and Docs, even Backups, but not any App data. I have selected the Apps I want to sync - Stocks for example - with iCloud on my device, but they are not syncing up with iCloud or my other Apple devices.  What are the steps for manually syncing an Apple device to iCloud?

Note:  I believe that Backups are not the same syncing data.  What exactly is the purpose of a Backup anyway?  Why for instance do photos need to "backed up" on the iCloud if iCloud is already a repo for photos.

Comment: It is up to the app developer to write code to sync to iCloud so the setup for each app is different.

Comment: There is no manual sync with iCloud. It’s on or off for a specific “bucket”. Could you edit this to focus on one specific app on one specific os? That might help us help you better.

Comment: A "sync" is so that photos are the same on all Apple devices signed into your iCloud account. So if you delete it on your phone, it goes away everywhere. **Backup** on the other hand makes a copy of (for example) your photos so that if you delete a photo you wanted to keep you can restore it. *They are two completely different things.*

Comment: This is more than one question, but in any case, I have found the sync is working.  I was expecting it to sync sooner, or more frequently, but it did eventually sync my Stock app data.

Comment: It would be nice though if the iCloud settings were persisted somehow after signing out of the iCloud. I notice that every time i sign out and back in, all the original settings are restored.  This is annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a lot to digest, but Apple’s iCloud article does a good job explaining what backup does.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428

In a nutshell, backup is a safety net that helps you a day after you realize  you made a mistake deleting photos that synchronize that deletion across all your devices (or worse, if the sync breaks and deletes all your photos from a mistake you didn’t make).

Sync helps if you lose your phone to use a web app version of Apple apps (contacts, mail, photos, calendar) but not so much for third party apps for which there isn’t a web app.

As to performance, you may speed up iCloud substantially by using a Mac on your local network to cache the iCloud data.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-content-caching-on-mac-mchl3b6c3720/mac

This helps especially if more than one device syncs or you sign out and back in to the same iCloud device to troubleshoot.